# What does "communicated" mean in a CV?

Tags: paper-submission, cv, terminology

I often see in a CV that certain papers are labelled as ‘communicated’. What does that mean? (Not ‘communicated by’.)

E.g. [this document](http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/172148/3/03_list%20of%20papers%20of%20the%20candidate.pdf) which is a list of papers including entries like:

> 5. ***"On complicated things and related stuff"*** (with A. B. Coauthor) (***communicated***).

Comment: Using unknown terms in your CV may be a problem.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @NateEldredge: This tends to get used in journals such as [PNAS](https://www.pnas.org).

Comment: @aeismail: It sounds to me like OP is asking about something different from this, since they write "not 'communicated by'" and have a reference to CVs.  But I'm not sure exactly what OP really is asking and I hope they will clarify with a specific example.

Comment: In the example posted no journal names are mentioned with the 'communicated' papers, so my guess would be that it essentially means 'submitted'.

Comment: Since there are no Journal names included  Pieter Naaijkens is probably right. In some journals there are also "rapid communications", in principle it could refer to that as well?

Answer (score 2):

"Communicated" means the manuscript is submitted to a journal and is currently under review.

Answer (score -1):

I think these are conference papers.